# Azure - Trigger which copies multible blobs

Tags: function, azure, copy, blob

I am currently working on a ServiceBus trigger (using C#) which copies and moves related blobs to another blob storage and Azure Data Lake. After copying, the function has to emit a notification to trigger further processing tasks. Therefore, I need to know, when the copy/move task has been finished.
My first approach was to use a Azure Function which copies all these files. However, Azure Functions have a processing time limit of 10 minutes (when manually set) and therefore it seems to be not the right solution. I was considering calling azCopy or StartCopyAsync() to perform an asynchronous copy, but as far as I understand, the processing time of the function will be as long as azCopy takes. To solve the time limit problem, I could use WebJobs instead, but there are also other technologies like Logic Apps, Durable Azure functions, Batch jobs, etc. which makes me confused about choosing the right technology for this problem. The function won't be called every second but might copy large data. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that Azure Functions only have a time limit when using consumption plan. If there is no better solution for copy blob tasks, I'll go for Azure Functions.